# Dreamweaver not recognizing symbolic link as directory

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, symbolic-link, symlink

I have this directory

```
drwxrwxr-x  6 awdfiles                pasgroup                4096 Jan 31 17:20 awdfiles
```

Which I want to access via another FTP connection.  The user is part of the `pasgroup`

I traverse to the root html directory of my desired user and create the symlink

```
$ cd rayhawkpas/dev
$ ln -s ../../awdfiles awdfiles
lrwxrwxrwx  1 rayhawkpas rayhawkpas   14 Feb  6 13:06 awdfiles -> ../../awdfiles
```

However, when I try to download the directory in dreamweaver it looks like this

[image]

It seems to not recognize that it's a directory.

I tried symlinking to a specific file to make sure my permissions were right

```
ln -s ../../awdfiles/themes/1/includes/header.php test.php
```

This worked fine. It showed up in dreamweaver and I was able to download and upload the file.

Comment: What OS is this?  Is it a Mac, or a Linux/Wine thing going on?

Comment: Linux / CentOS.

Comment: Um...  How are you running Dreamweaver then?

Comment: Server is linux. My machine is Windows 7, CS5.5. I've done links like this before without issue so I'm not really sure what's going on

Comment: Oh!  The symbolic link is on the server, and you are connected via ftp...   This may be a limit/option of the FTP server.  It would be a security issue to allow symbolic links over FTP because you could make it point anywhere...  That's just my guess though...  What hosting provider are you using?

Comment: Also, what's your website URL?

Comment: @Kevin What's the URL have anything to do with FTP Symlinks??

Comment: @Chris I was going to use nmap to figure out what FTP server it's running and then look up how it deals with symbolic links...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FTP Server is not configured to follow symlinks.
When configured this way a symlink will appear as a common file, just as you describe.
Change it's configuration. You haven't mentioned what software so I can't say how.

**Edit:**
vsFTPd will not allow synlinks that link outside the user's chroot. There's no way around that.

A possible workaround is to mount the target of the proposed symlink as a subdirectory of the chroot environment. This is an ugly kludge, but the only way around the issue using vsFTPD.

A possible alternatives, install and use a different FTPd, or use a different protocol such as SFTP. I'm not sure if Dreamweaver supports SFTP, if it doesn't you can get around that with a utility that mounts SFTP drives as Windows Network Drives (I use such a utility, ExpandDrive, but there are others).

Comment: apache/centos..

Comment: As far as I can tell followsymlinks is on. it's in my httpd.conf, virtual hosts file and htaccess

Comment: Unless you installed mod_ftp or mina, "Apache" is not your FTP software. While I'm at it, "Apache" is a company name, not software at all. They're most famous software is their web server "httpd".

Comment: This is why I'm asking questions and you're answering them. If I knew what I was doing I wouldn't be here.

Comment: So what FTP software are you running then?

Comment: I do not know..

Comment: You'll have to figure that one out before I can help you further. May I suggest [unix.se] as a good place to ask "How to determine what FTP software my CentOS VPS is running"

Comment: vsftpd 9 more chars